# Issue with object modified after supertest response inside nested for loops

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, supertest

My code looks like this:

```
let fs = require('fs');
let path = require('path');
let supertest = require('supertest');
let json = require('../../Util/json');
let chai = require('chai');
let assert = chai.assert;

let client = supertest("some_base_url");

describe('My test suite', function () {

    it('My sample test', () => {
        let results = {};
        fs.readdirSync("some_dir").forEach(dir => {
            fs.readdirSync("some_dir" + dir).forEach(file => {
                console.log(`Found file ${file} in directory ${dir}`);
                let json_file = "some_dir" + dir + path.sep + file;
                let data = fs.readFileSync(json_file, 'utf8');
                if (dir !== undefined) {
                    let url = dir + file.split('.')[0];
                    console.log("Request endpoint:", url);
                    client.get(url)
                        .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
                        .expect(200)
                        .end(function (error, response) {
                            if (error) {
                                console.log("Error:", error);
                            } else {
                                data_obj = JSON.parse(data);
                                result_obj = JSON.parse(response.text);
                                results[dir + '-' + file] = json.assertJson(data_obj, result_obj); // assertJson results boolean value
                            }
                        });
                } else {
                    console.log(`Could not find any endpoint defined for ${dir}, skipping tests for the same.`);
                }
            });
        });
        console.log("Results:",JSON.stringify(results, null, 2));
        assert(!Object.values(results).includes(false));
    });
});
```

The problem is that the `results` object is empty when printed outside the outer for loop, but gives properly populated output when printed inside the for loop. In spite of the fact that my code is synchronous and there are no promises used, I wonder why this is happening.

**EDIT:** After doing some experiments (like commenting out the `supertest` code in my code and simply modifying the `results` object inside the for loop), I get expected output for `results` outside the for loops. So I believe there's something wrong with the way I'm using `supertest`. I intend to use it in a synchronous way.

Comment: try **var results = {};**

Comment: I had forgotten to **declare** `results`. I get the same output with `let` as well as `var` anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find any obvious ways to use `supertest` in a synchronous way, so I resolved the issue for myself by using [sync-request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sync-request).

Answer (score 2):

Since Node.js favors asynchronous, if you put log outside for loop then log will be printed first as it'll take less time for execution compared to execution time of your for loop.

You can try out such combinations here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

For example:

```
var array1 = ['a'];
var array2 = ['d', 'e', 'f'];

array1.forEach(function(element1) {
  array2.forEach(function(element2) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log(element2);
        }, 1000)
  });
});
console.log("Hello");
```

Output:

> "Hello"
>
> "d"
>
> "e"
>
> "f"

Comment: Ah, I see. So would you like to suggest any solution to my problem?

Comment: @WSMathias9 Yes to demonstrate that it won't be blocking every time as if any of the loop takes more time than execution of log then log will be printed first

Comment: @AkshayMaldhure Sure, please provide more details about the usecase you're trying to solve here.

Comment: So does that imply there's some "asynchronous" code in my code? BTW, I need to iterate over the files in multiple directories (and hence two for loops), read the contents from each of the files and compare the contents against the response text from relevant APIs.

Comment: Yes, to deal with such situation you can use async (https://www.npmjs.com/package/async). It provides many functions to deal with asynchronous JavaScript and you can choose function according to your use case.

Comment: But I do not want any part of my code to be asynchronous. So I don't think that would be a solution for me.

Comment: I think [sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sync) is more useful if you want call any asynchronous function in synchronous way.

Comment: @Ashish I did some experiment and found that using `supertest` is causing this "issue" to me.

Comment: @AkshayMaldhure Might be as that's the only piece of code which can take time for execution inside for loop :)

Comment: @Ashish Do you have any ideas with regards to making it synchronous?

Comment: @AkshayMaldhure You can use glob (https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) to get the file names and it can trace nested folders to get all files within nested folders so it'll eliminate your both forEach loop and it'll give you array of file names using which you can process these files with your supertest client.